# Why I have infity loop in useEffect when I use websocket?

Tags: reactjs, websocket, use-effect

I adding weboscket to application at now I must try to update array of active users when adde new users, but when I put in useEffect in result paramter [activeUsersInGallery] then sending request to webosocket infitiy. I don't now why.

```
function Seller() {
const [activeUsersInGallery, setActiveUsersInGallery] = useState([]);
  const [checkMultipleClient, setCheckMultipleClient] = useState([]);

  function goToCheckCustomer(idClient) {
      setCheckMultipleClient([...checkMultipleClient, idClient]);
  }

  async function connectionToWebSocketRooms() {
      let response = await getConnection();
      return response
  }

  async function getActiveUsers(pageNumber) {
      let response = await connectionToWebSocketRooms();
      let data = await response
          .invoke("GetActiveUsers", pageNumber);
      await response
          .on("updateActiveUsers", (user, operationType) => updateActiveUsers(user, operationType))
          setActiveUsersInGallery(data);
          console.log(data)
      return data;
  }

  function updateActiveUsers(user, operationType) {
    console.log(user)
      if ( operationType === 'update' || operationType === 'add') {
          setActiveUsersInGallery([...activeUsersInGallery, user])
          return activeUsersInGallery
      } else if (operationType === 'remove'){
          const removeClientOnArray = [...activeUsersInGallery.filter(filterArrWhenRemoveUser => filterArrWhenRemoveUser.id !== user.id)];
          setActiveUsersInGallery(removeClientOnArray);
      }
  }

  useEffect(() => {
      getActiveUsers(1);  
  }, [activeUsersInGallery]);
return (
//...some code
) 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`useEffect` triggers everytime `activeUsersInGallery` changes reference. In your case the issue is here

```
  async function getActiveUsers(pageNumber) {
      let response = await connectionToWebSocketRooms();
      let data = await response
          .invoke("GetActiveUsers", pageNumber);
      await response
          .on("updateActiveUsers", (user, operationType) => updateActiveUsers(user, operationType))
          setActiveUsersInGallery(data);
          console.log(data)
      return data;
  }
```

a new object reference is created on the response of this  code `await response.invoke("GetActiveUsers", pageNumber)`